# Symfony2, Configure pdo session storage in database

Tags: php, session, symfony, pdo

For my Symfony2 project, i'm using the session storage in a database.

So, i configure my config.yml like that :

```
framework:
    session:
        handler_id:     session.handler.pdo

parameters:
    pdo.db_options:
        db_table:    session
        db_id_col:   session_id
        db_data_col: session_value
        db_time_col: session_time

services:
    pdo:
        class: PDO
        arguments:
            - "pgsql:host=%database_host%;dbname=%database_name%"
            - "%database_user%"
            - "%database_password%"
        calls:
            - [setAttribute, [3, 2]]

    session.handler.pdo:
        class:     Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler
        arguments: ["@pdo", "%pdo.db_options%"]
```

All it's ok, when i login, an entry is created in my database and the sessions works fine.

But, how can i define the lifetime of my session when its in the database ? Why do I have a lot of lines (+50) in my session table, if I only have 4 members on my application ?

How can i configure that ? I just need one session when a member login.

Comment: you found solutions? I have too very many old sessions in database :(

Comment: I think the anwser i accepted is the good way.. but i really don't know i it works or not ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the number of rows in your session table by running the session garbage collector more frequently.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability

In your php.ini file

session.gc_probability=1

session.gc_divisor=1

session.gc_maxlifetime=36000

These settings will run the garbage collector with 100% probability, which is *not* recommended for production but you should be able to verify it works and tweak the settings as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the number of rows is *not* dictated by session lifetime, at least not entirely.

The major reason for so much rows is protection from session hijacking. So, if you close the browser and come back to your web-site, session is not just being taken for granted but **regenerated instead**.

Are you using `FOSUserBundle` for authentication? I know for sure that it supports configuration of session hijacking protection...

**EDIT:**

**`chrsva`** mentioned it here:
[How does Symfony2 session fixation work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129699/how-does-symfony2-session-fixation-work)

Comment: Yep, i'm using FOSUser. And i haven't a website, i have a phonegap application

Comment: Yes, web-site what just my generic way of saying web application :)

Comment: So, what can i do ? Nothing ? If i have 8 000 000 lines in two month for just 10 members... ?

Comment: Whoa, that's a lot! I'm trying to find some reference on session regeneration in Symfony2 (I know I have seen it before). Updating the question as soon as I find it ;)

Comment: OK, I think I've found it... updated the answer. As it turns out, it has nothing to do with FOSUserBundle itself but with `security` instead :)

Comment: Don't understand the use of session_fixation_strategy