# Symfony2 - PDO sessions - Do I need to delete records manually or is everything automatic?

Tags: php, symfony, session, pdo

I've implemented PDO session storage (= sessions are now saved in a mysql database table).
This is the symfony2 reference:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html

If I visit a page of my webapp (even without loggin-in) 2 records are added to my session table. Is this normal? (2 records for a user)
Then, if I log in, those 2 records are changed (but no record is added).
Finally, if I log out, the 2 records change again, but nothing is deleted.

If everything unitl now is correct, how/when will the records of expired sessions be deleted from the db table? Do I need to implement a cronjob or will symfony do that automatically?

So, do I need to do something (= write some specific code) or not?

I've found this question:
[Symfony2, Configure pdo session storage in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785275/symfony2-configure-pdo-session-storage-in-database)
Is the garbage collector the one responsible for deleting the records in the session table? Is it active by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be automatic by default but expired session are not deleted on each request but rather according to some  probability (default is 1% chance).

**\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler**

```
public function gc($maxlifetime)
{
    // delete the session records that have expired
    $sql = "DELETE FROM $this->table WHERE $this->timeCol < :time";

    try {
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':time', time() - $maxlifetime, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('PDOException was thrown when trying to delete expired sessions: %s', $e->getMessage()), 0, $e);
    }

    return true;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/sessionhandlerinterface.gc.php

You can also set invalidate_session key for logout provider. It should destroy session from database.

```
logout:
    invalidate_session: true
```

Comment: Nice answer!! But are you sure the default probability is 1%? Somewhere I've read it is 1/1000 = 0,1%

Comment: [http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability). PHP manual says 1/100 but look at your php.ini for true answer.